# Not able to insert data into Cassandra./

Tags: cassandra

I have a question regarding inserting data to Cassandra.

I have deleted a row key from a Column Family(CF) after some time I am trying insert data with the same rowkey.

The program gets executed but when I try to access the data with the rowkey from command line I get zero results.

Why is this happening? I know there is some thing called "Tombstone" with each deleted key.

But I am trying to insert the data after compaction.

I have set my `<GCGraceSeconds> 0 </GCGraceSeconds>.`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

probably your delete is happening with a larger timestamp than the insert you did later.

Comment: Yes..I am deleting it with a very high time stamp. Can I please know the reason why I can not insert the data when deleted with higher timestamp?

Comment: @Sandeep this is years late, but in case other people come by here and wonder, the answer is because of tombstones, as you suggested. Cassandra does deletion by inserting tombstone markers, which have timestamps just like columns do. If a (row or column) tombstone has a higher timestamp than a corresponding column, the tombstone wins and the column (or row) is considered not to exist.

Answer (score 2):

How many nodes do you have?  Are their clocks synchronized accurately? If not, this could cause inconsistencies.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this same problem happening but I haven't been able to debug it. Currently I'm checking http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/FAQ#range_ghosts to see if that is causing the problem. Maybe it will help you too.